# Kali Linux cant detect disks

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, installation, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux

I just made a partition for Kali to install it there as my second OS.
My bootable USB-Stick works fine, but when I try to install kali, it is detecting the USB-Stick as only usable disk.

How to install it on my kali partition?

Comment: Usually such problems have to do with an incompatible SATA mode in UEFI. Choose AHCI instead of RAID, Intel RST or others but if dual-booting with Windows make sure to install AHCI drivers in Windows first or it won't boot. But Kali is for professionals and professionals should know that already? And they should also know that Kali isn't meant to be installed and it isn't a normal desktop Linux for daily usage? It seems you're trying to run before being able to walk...

Comment: some specific errors and screenshots would be useful

Answer (score 1):

The trouble could it be due that the Kali Linux bootable installation USB does not recognize the Main OS partition so the installation partition has to be done using the customized menú of the Kali Linux USB driver on the machine booting the Computer from the USB drive, the customized installation is done on Graphical Installation menú. Additionally if the OS is going to be used for security audits is better run Kali as a live versión otherwise final user data security can be compromised. 
The following files have useful information: 
https://blog.usejournal.com/installing-kali-linux-from-usb-1db84c1c7569 
https://docks.kali.org/installation/Kali-linux-hard-disk-install